# AutoMapper not mapping correctly when same type

Tags: .net, automapper

I got a problem with the AutoMapper (3.1.1 on .NET 4.5) library is very strange, i will appreciate your help.

I got four objects:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public Address House { get; set; }
    public Address Office { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetailEntity
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public Guid HouseId { get; set; }
    public Guid? OfficeId { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressEntity House { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressEntity Office { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class AddressEntity
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

And with this scenario:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressEntity>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetail, UserDetailEntity>()
    .ForMember("Office", s => s.MapFrom(ud => ud.Office));


UserDetailEntity entity = Mapper.Map<UserDetail, UserDetailEntity>(dto);

Assert.AreEqual(dto.House.Street, entity.House.Street);
Assert.AreEqual(dto.Office.Street, entity.Office.Street);
```

The Assert fails in the office address I always get the House address :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem, AutoMapper uses the GetHashCode to determine if two objects are the same, and as I override this method, on this scenario the hashcode is the same.

Comment: Could you update the post with working code mate? It would be interesting to see the solution.

Comment: The code works, the problem was that UserDetail inherits from a BaseDTO which override the method GetHashCode and for the objects Address (Office and House) the hash code calculated is the same, so for AutoMapper the object is the same, so same mapped.

Comment: Does that mean AutoMapper won't map any identical classes or was it a case of expanding the "create map" function?

Comment: AutoMapper does, but as I override native methods as "GetHashCode" for me objects, which automapper uses doesn´t work.

Comment: I was able to cast or declare the type as an object and that worked. I am not sure what a more proper and elegant answer would look like.